# RelativeLayout disappears

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

My example layout! 
In portrait mode, it's OK, but when I turn, 
scrolling works properly and there is no button at all!button is disappears! What's wrong?Help!
My example layout! 
In portrait mode, it's OK, but when I turn, 
scrolling works properly and there is no button at all!button is disappears! What's wrong?Help!

```
My example layout!
```

In portrait mode, it's OK, but when I turn, 
scrolling works properly and there is no button at all!button is disappears! What's wrong?Help!
My example layout! 
In portrait mode, it's OK, but when I turn, 
scrolling works properly and there is no button at all!button is disappears! What's wrong?Help!

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainScroller">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
        android:id="@+id/calendarLinear"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_click"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:contentDescription="@string/iconCalendar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/vylet"
            android:id="@+id/tvDepart"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/lineHeight"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/separate_line" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/prilet"
            android:id="@+id/tvArrive"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/mainTextStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_click"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
        android:background="@color/vColor"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/footerRelative">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@style/btnStyle"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste your whole xml layout,looks like outset layout doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this move your Relative layout on top of the ScrollView

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
      android:id="@+id/footerRelative">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainScroller">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
        android:id="@+id/calendarLinear"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_click"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:contentDescription="@string/iconCalendar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/vylet"
            android:id="@+id/tvDepart"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/lineHeight"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/separate_line" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/prilet"
            android:id="@+id/tvArrive"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/mainTextStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_click"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
        android:background="@color/vColor"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@style/btnStyle"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now Your complete layout will be shown!, and your button will be at bottom always.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are able to see the complete layout in portrait just because portrait layout is having more space and your complete layout is fitting well, but landscape is having lesser space.

As landscape has lesser space than portrait, you are able to view only top scrollview so only that portion would be scrollable!

**How to solve?**

Keep your layout above to the button layout, so your button would be visible all the time at bottom!

```
android:layout_above="@+id/footerRelative"
```

Comment: i tried! But linearlayout disappears! Only button remainded!

Comment: like this? **<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            style="@style/btnStyle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footerRelative"
            />**

Comment: Not in button, but add that in ScrollView